# JQuery DatePicker -> dateformat, how to output dayNamesMin instead of dayNamesShort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, localization, datepicker

Hi there i am trying to output the selection of a date. Using the D option gives me days like 'Thu' or 'Mon'. When i try to localize this format using the 'nl' localisation, the the output is again nicely in 3 letters such as 'don' or 'maa'

But for parsing the date (using Javascript) into the Dutch language i need to have the 'do' and 'ma' so the dayNamesMin. Is there a way that i can configure JQuery datepicker the correct localized day?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `altFormat` option of the jQuery UI date picker, this should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Strange enough, you cannot specify a date format with `dayNamesMin`. You can, however, specify `dayNamesShort` and `dayNames` in your options. So, for example, you could copy `dayNamesMin` to `dayNamesShort` and use `D` in your date format.

```
var minDays = $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dayNamesMin');
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dayNamesShort', minDays);
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/bBA9F/3/.

Note that, for some reason, the `#datepicker` div wouldn't be hidden after the two statements above, hence the last statement in the jsfiddle.